# Unity does not load - VirtualBox

Tags: unity, virtualbox, 15.10

I have the same problem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

I tried almost all the solutions described on that post:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

(when switching to graphic - nothing's there).

or

```
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

and then `setsid unity` or `unity --reset-icons &disown`.

I tried reinstalling `unity` and `ubuntu-desktop`.

I also tried removing: `rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1` and `rm .Xauthority`.

None of these helped. Still having the same blank desktop with no icons/bar.

I am using VirtualBox Version 5.0.24 r108355.
Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Guest Additions solved it.

```
cd /media/your_user/VBOXADDITIONS_x.x.xx_xxxxxx
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
sudo reboot
```

See [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm/22745#22745) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the graphics controller to VBoxSVGA (was VBoxVGA) solved the problem.

VirtualBox settings for the VM -> Display -> click dropdown for Graphics Controller and select VBoxSVGA.

My symptoms: Recently, Unity stopped loading properly for an Ubuntu 14.04 VM I'd been using for years. I tried many suggested solutions online, before and after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, with no success.  Using VirtualBox 6.0.8.